# (node:26) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a code where i want to let the bot send a random image. But the image in the channel is not loading

And i get this error:

(node:26) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.

```
at Function.normalizeField (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:452:14
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalizeFields (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
at MessageEmbed.addField (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:257:17)
at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:117:2)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Code:

```js
var images = ["https://i.imgur.com/7mUR1Pl.jpg", "https://imgur.com/eH9gPXu", "https://imgur.com/60YLPki" ];
var image = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "!gtafoto") {    
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Hier is je GTA foto!')
      .setColor("#f1c40f")
      .setFooter('Mogelijk gemaakt door Gijs#0001')
      .setImage(String([images[image]]))

    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the only link to an image is the first one (ends with .png), the other two are link to the page of the image, which cannot be displayed as an image itself. You only need to add `.png` to the end of every link that doesn't already have one.